# Какое имя используется при публикации приложения в AppStore?

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple, appstore

Доброго времени суток.

Подхожу к моменту публикации приложения в **AppStore** и столкнулся с вопросом. У меня к **AppleID** привязана виртуальная карта **Tinkoff Bank** и имя в настройках **iCloud** (Настройки -> iCloud, под фотографией) - **TINKOFF WALLET**. При смене имени в настройках, система пишет, что платежные данные неправильные.

Если я буду публиковать приложение, повлияет это имя как-то на мое отображение в **AppStore**? И если да, то можно ли будет в процессе публикации заменить имя?

Спасибо.

Comment: Спросите в поддержке Apple?

Comment: Я думаю люди, которые публикуют свое приложение - знают ответа. Проще его получить от них)

Comment: ...и не знать, насколько он правильный. Я б в таких делах кому попало доверять не стал :)

Comment: у вас имя пользователся tinkoff wallet?

Comment: Имя пользователя мака - другое, а именно в "настройки -> iCloud" (между фотографией и кнопкой "учетная запись") выводится Tinkoff Wallet. Я так понял, имя берется из кардхолдера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя будет использоваться которое вы будите использовать в  developer.apple.com и itunesconnect.apple.com. По факту вы можете написать что хотите.